# Understanding express and how to use it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, server

Many times I have created apps with express where I just spin up a server at a port and then on the client side do all the stuff. whether that be fetching with fetch/axios, rendering data, and even changing routes (react-router). I have never hugely explored node or the server part, until now....hopefully.

I get what it's doing partially. in terms of

`app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))`

this just sends the response to the browser window. and I have even managed to do this:

```
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Listening");

    fetch(url, {

    }).then((res => res.json()))
    .then((json => console.log('json')))
    .catch(() => {
        console.log("bbb");
    });
});
```

and this logs all the data into the sever window. however, I have a couple of questions

should I be doing this in the server or the client? whats the advantage?

secondly, once I have this data, how can I send it to the client? i.e. a react component

also, I cant seem to copy this code and get it work inside `app.get()`? am I doing it wrong? maybe I have misunderstood there

I understood more than questions, an answer to all would be great but I would just like to have some more knowledge on what goes inside express and the server

Comment: "_should I be doing this in the server or the client?_" what does "this" refer to? I'm afraid your question is very broad and in general reading tutorials and documentations about nodejs, dynamic content and similar.

Answer (score 0):

> should I be doing this in the server or the client? whats the advantage?

You have to consider the followig things when requesting another server:

Serverside:

- you can share the data to multiple clients
- you can keep algorithms / secrets private
- you probably have a better bandwith than your clients, so you can load big chunks of data and then only send the neccessary data to the client

Client:

- Does not consume your servers ressources

> secondly, once I have this data, how can I send it to the client? i.e. a react component

You can use AJAX, websockets (http://socket.io) or you have to use redirects.

> also, I cant seem to copy this code and get it work inside app.get()?

If you expected to see the data at the client, you have to `res.json(json)`.

Comment: ok that's really helpful, thanks. one question, just on the last point. what have you said has worked but when I said send to client I meant, is it possible/correct way to do things by sending it to a component and then getting the client to render it? currently it's just appearing actually in the browser window. I was wondering if I could send the data to my react component state and then do something with it?

Comment: ok cheers thanks, can you give me a good link for AJAX please? will accept your answer